# Closed form detection in C#.net

Tags: .net

I am new in .net.I need help.
I have 2 forms one form has logic and second form has login section.I want to run second (login) form first.I am doing it by writing code  Application.Run(new Sign_in()); in first form constructor.And my second form is appearing first but when i just closed the Login form after clicking on Closed icon (RED Cross icon) my first logic data form is being load.I don't want to load my first form without login in any how condition.
what i should to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `LoginForm.Close()`, call `LogicForm.Show()` and then `LoginForm.Hide()`

Answer (score 2):

Running a form in a form's constructor is generally going to end badly. I would separate these out, i.e. in your `Main()` method

```
bool loggedIn = false;
using(var loginForm = new SignInForm()) {
    if(loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        loggedIn = true; // plus whatever else you need; maybe a "Principal"
    }
}
if(loggedIn) {
    using(var mainForm = new SomeOtherForm()) {
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

You would also change the login form to set the `DialogResult` appropriately.